# How can I extend the res object in express and use the extended property in a error middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

Here's the response-hander.js middleware file. I have 2 function that extend the res object normal behavior. If I use these function in a normal route everything works fine, the problem shows when I try to call one of these in another middleware.

```
var responseHandler;

responseHandler = function(req, res, next) {

    res.jsonSuccess = function(results) {
        res.status(200).json({ 
            status: "OK",
            results: results 
        });
    };

    res.jsonBadRequest = function(message) {
        res.status(400).json({ 
            status: "BAD_REQUEST",
            error_message: message
        });
    };

    next(); 
};

module.exports = responseHandler;
```

Here's the error-handler.js middleware:

```
var errorHandler;

errorHandler = function(error, req, res, next){
    if (error instanceof Error) {
        res.jsonBadRequest("Error.");
    } 
}

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

The error:

```
TypeError: res.jsonBadRequest is not a function
```

Example:

This works

```
app.get("/my/route", function(req, res) {
    return res.jsonBadRequest("Test");
});
```

This doesn't

```
app.get("/my/route", function(req, res) {
    // the error middleware gets calld but dosn't find my function.
    throw new Error();
});
```

Comment: Is `res.locals` what you're looking for: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals?

Comment: If you're after a simple way to send standardised errors from various routes, I've approached this in my projects by creating custom exception classes and throwing those, letting the default express error handler deal with sending the error to the client. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw#Throw_an_object for a guide to constructing your own error classes

Comment: @TomJardine-McNamara Yes It's basically what i want to do. Though problem is not in throwing and catching the errors, but in calling a custom response function as shown above inside the default experss error handler middleware.